# Show a true modal dialog box without button

Tags: android

The following code will produce a truely model dialog box, with close button. Truely model means, when you click on the area other than dialog box, the dialog box will remain active and will not close.

```
AlertDialog alert = builder
    .setCancelable(false)
    .setPositiveButton(context.getResources().getString(R.string.about_close), null)
    .create();
alert.show();
```

The following will produce a dialog box without close button. When you click on the area other than dialog box, the dialog box will be closed.

```
AlertDialog alert = builder
    .setCancelable(false)
    .create();
alert.show();
```

Is there any way I can have a truely model dialog, without button?

Comment: do you want some thing like this http://i.stack.imgur.com/xSqN1.png

Comment: i tried your second code. it doesn't close when you click on screen other than the dialog box.

Comment: @HirenDabhi, Tablet honeycomb will do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is better to make a custom alert-dialogbox. For more help check [this](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-custom-dialog-example/)